# Understanding big o notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a question about calculating big o notation for the following code:

```
j = 1;
while ( j <= n ) do  
  for i = 1 to j do 
    O(1); 
  endfor; 
  j=j*2; 
endwhile
```

So far, I have that the loop is calculated Σ<sub>i=1,..,n</sub>2<sup>i</sup>.  It looks like a geometric sequence, but I'm not sure what the big O value would be. Can anyone help out?

Comment: You need to simplify the summation that you have. There is a simple closed formula for it, which should be readily found on Google.

Answer (score 3):

It's **not** gaussian here as it is a **geometric sequence** as you already mentioned.

The outer while loop will stop once j reaches n.

The number of iterations needed for that can be calculated by taking `log₂(n)` as it is the question `2^x = n` that is to solve here. (How many times do we have to keep multiplying by two until we reach n)

Interestingly enough this leads to:

```
log₂(n)     log₂(n)
∑ 2^i    =  2       - 1 = n - 1
0
```

`Sum from 1 to log2(n) taken over 2^i` which is exactly `2^(log2n) - 1` = `n - 1` (restating the formula given above in case your fontset doesn't support the required unicode chars)

Using the fact here that

```
k            k+1
∑ 2^i    =  2   - 1
0
```

So the algorithm should be **O(n)**.

Alternatively you might calculate the sum with the **generic formula** for geometric sequences:

```
Sn = a0 * (1-q^n) / (1-q)
```

which should lead to the same result which in fact it does:

```
        log₂n
   1 - 2           1 - n
  -----------  =  ------ = n - 1
    1 - 2           -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Geometric sequence is correct.  Take a quick example.  If n is 8, then the number of iterations of the inner loop is 1, then 2, then 4, then 8.  If n were 7 you'd have 1, 2, 4, and no 8.  So the number of O(1) operations is going to vary between n and 2n - 1 as you increase n.  On either side of that range, the order is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Ok!, Let us assume some values to help understand better:

Let n be equal to 4

```
So now:
j=1 ( <4 ) => loop runs 1 time = O(1)
j=1*2 = 2 ( <4 ) => loop runs 2 times = 2*O(1)
j=2*2 = 4 ( =4 ) => loop runs 4 times = 4*O(1)
```

If n is of the type 2^x, then one can safely say that the series of loop runs would look like:

O(1) + 2*O(1) + 4*O(1) + 8*O(1) + 16*O(1) + ..... + n*O(1). = 1*(2^(x+1) - 1)*O(1)/(2-1) 
= (2n-1)*O(1) = O(n)
Where n = 2^x, and the outer loop runs x+1 times.

Now if n is not of the type 2^x. Let's say n = 6.

```
So now:
j=1 ( <6 ) => loop runs 1 time = O(1)
j=1*2 = 2 ( <6 ) => loop runs 2 times = 2*O(1)
j=2*2 = 4 ( <6 ) => loop runs 4 times = 4*O(1)
j=2*4 = 8 ( >6 ) => loop exits.
```

It is clear that the outer loop will run only 2^( floor value( log base 2(n) )) + 1 times. And this value would be the effective n.

So let us put it into the formula: (2n-1)*O(1)
=> (2*(2^(floorValue(logBase2(n))) - 1)*O(1) is approximately equal to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

To be a little smart-ass here: What you are asking for is actually `Theta`. Your code is `Theta(n)` - but also `O(n)`, `O(n * log_2(n))` or even `O(n!)` since Big-O is only **an** upper bound. `Theta` is precise.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 0(n^2).
This is the same as  insertion sort

```
void insertionsort(void){

 for(int x=1;x<n;x++){
   int temp= array[x];
   for(int y=x-1;  y>=0 && array[y]>temp ;y--){
    array[y+1]=array[y];
   }array[y+1]=temp;
 }
}
```

O(n) as it goes from 1 to n, but for each of those, it goes from y=x-1 upto 0.
In worst case, it will always go from y=x-1 to 0. so this grows for every time x grows.

This is the case with your one.